# Get acronyms always in long form

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I'm using the `glossaries` package for handling my acronyms. It's pretty fine but I would like to have always to long form instead of the short after the first use with the use of `\gls`.

Does anybody know how I can manage to use `\gls` and have the long form after the first appearance (**without** using `\glsentrylong` or `\acrlong`)?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\newacronym[longplural={acronyms},shortplural={ACRs}]{REF}{ACR}{acronym}

\begin{document}
\noindent
First use: \Gls{REF}\\
2nd and following use: \gls{REF}

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

I currently get this:

[image: What I get]

I would need this:

[image: What I would need]

Answer (score 1):

The command `\glsgenacfmt` determines what exactly is printed when you typeset an acronym with `\gls` and friends. It uses the `\glsentryshort` (and the uppercase and plural forms) when the acronym has already been used.

We can redefine `\glsgenacfmt` and replace all instances of `entryshort` with `entrylong`. Then we get:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\renewcommand*{\glsgenacfmt}{%
  \ifdefempty\glscustomtext{%
    \ifglsused\glslabel{%
      \glsifplural{%
        \glscapscase
          {\acronymfont{\glsentrylongpl{\glslabel}}\glsinsert}%
          {\acronymfont{\Glsentrylongpl{\glslabel}}\glsinsert}%
          {%
            \mfirstucMakeUppercase
              {\acronymfont{\glsentrylongpl{\glslabel}}\glsinsert}%
          }%
      }%
      {%
        \glscapscase
          {\acronymfont{\glsentrylong{\glslabel}}\glsinsert}%
          {\acronymfont{\Glsentrylong{\glslabel}}\glsinsert}%
          {%
            \mfirstucMakeUppercase
              {\acronymfont{\glsentrylong{\glslabel}}\glsinsert}%
          }%
      }%
    }%
    {%
      \glsifplural{%
        \glscapscase
          {\genplacrfullformat{\glslabel}{\glsinsert}}%
          {\Genplacrfullformat{\glslabel}{\glsinsert}}%
          {%
            \mfirstucMakeUppercase
              {\genplacrfullformat{\glslabel}{\glsinsert}}%
          }%
      }%
      {%
        \glscapscase
          {\genacrfullformat{\glslabel}{\glsinsert}}%
          {\Genacrfullformat{\glslabel}{\glsinsert}}%
          {%
            \mfirstucMakeUppercase
             {\genacrfullformat{\glslabel}{\glsinsert}}%
          }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  {\glscustomtext}%
}

\setacronymstyle{long-short}

\newacronym[longplural={acronyms},shortplural={ACRs}]{REF}{ACR}{acronym}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

First use: \Gls{REF} \par
2nd and following use: \Gls{REF} and \gls{REF}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Disclaimer: *I am not terribly familiar with `glossaries` and I do hope there is an easier way, but I haven't found one. (That doesn't mean there isn't one, of course.)*